# Native C++ and Java Android Library in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, java-native-interface

I have a native android library that I am trying to use from the Unity Edtor. The library is compiled into and aar file, and has both C++ and Java code. I have placed the AAR file inside the plugins folder and it works fine on the device, but does not work on the editor.

On the editor, I can successfully instantiate an AndroidJavaObject, but when I try to call one of its functions that return a string, I get a null. This works fine on  the target device, but I need it work on the editor for debugging purposes.

Do I have to set the JNI path by any chance for it to work? Do I have to have it in a different format like a .so?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible, Unity Editor does not provide this feature, use either a real device or emulator.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find an other way of getting it to work, and don't actually need the output from an actual device (since you're running it on the editor...) maybe you should just mock it for in-editor use:
where ever you call the plugin method, just have an #if Unity_Editor mock #else call #endif

Comment: Is there really no way of getting an Android native plugin to work on the editor? I cannot mock it as I have pieces of code doing some Image processing in the library